# Saving cached images from Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, images, download

I made my own webpage on my desktop, with images with a remote src value.  ie. the page was saved locally, but displayed images from a remote website.

I loaded the page in Google Chrome, waited for images to load, then right-clicked on an image, and chose save.  The image was then downloaded a second time from the remote website.

Why didn't Chrome use the local copy it had downloaded the first time?

Comment: Are you sure it is actually downloading the image? The browser would normally send a request to the server to check if it has modified and if it has not been modified then it can use the cached version. It may sometimes take a little time to copy the cached version to your download folder if it is a very big image.

Also a server can control caching and indeed disable it. It might be worth using Chrome's developer tools to check the request headers.

Answer (score 0):

If your on something other than Internet Explorer, here is a quick way to retrieve your cached files in almost all other browsers:

```
about:cache
```

It's on wikipedia about 2000px down.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme
```

Sorry. I'm not an IE user. You'll have to google it.